# Windows 8 and 8.1 clients showing printer offline after reconnecting to the network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-8, shared-printers, windows-8.1

The print server is 2008 R2 with the most recent updates. This happens most often after a resume from sleep or if the user takes their PC to their home network. A restart of the PC or a restart of the print spooler is the only solution so far to fix this at the client side.

I installed this hotfix below, but it is still occurring-

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2713128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Windows 8.1 that has now been fixed.
The KB [article 2961042](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2961042/en-us) has the details.
The fix is in the [update rollup May2014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2955164).

Thanks to [HopelessN00b](https://serverfault.com/users/118258/hopelessn00b) for the forum link that was eventually updated with solution.

Answer (score 0):

A band aid fix that we are using until windows comes out with a hotfix or update is turning off fast start-up on the windows 8 machines. (Control Panel ->Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do -> click Change settings that are currently unavailable -> uncheck Turn on fast startup (recommended) Then do a reboot.)